# Programmatically create a list of TextViews and ImageViews

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a parent RelativeLayout in my xml with id `relative_layout_bottom` in which I want to create a list of TextViews aligned to the left of the parent and a list of ImageViews aligned to the right of the parent programmatically. I have a map of  and want to iterate over this creating those layouts. I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work.

This is how I imagine it:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_bottom)

for each <TextView, ImageView> in map {

  create a TextView
  add it to the left of relativeLayout

  create an ImageView
  add it to the right of relativeLayout

}
```

edit: Would it be better to have two vertical LinearLayouts?

Comment: there is documentation on how to programmatically add views. The use of `LinearLayout` is probably not what you think, based on your question. Maybe practice or be more specific with your question(s) :)

Comment: i think that you missed `android.widget.ListView`

Comment: yes in your relative layout u can take two linear layout with vertical orientation. Add alignParentLeft to one linear layout and alignParentRight to another linear layout and add your widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinLayLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinLayRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now you can add views to linearlayouts programmatically.